# Rotate matrix elements

Tags: arrays, matrix, rotation

Given a 2D array A. Write a program that rotate/shift the elements of an array clockwise by one at a time.

Example:
Input
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 
9 10 11 12 
13 14 15 16

Output
5 1 2 3 
9 10 6 4 
13 11 7 8 
14 15 16 12

Comment: Are you asking us to code for you?

Comment: Array **A** as input  has 19 numbers in it.  The output has only 16 numbers.   Also, what language is this program supposed to be in?

Comment: @SriHarshaKappala I need the pseudo code not complete code.